# What to do about this loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, break

```
char restart = 'y';
while (restart == 'y')
{
    cin >> restart; 
    cout << "great keep playing\n";
}
cout << "thanks for playing\n";
```

When I run this code it also displays the code outside of the loop as well, I even tried using a break statement but it didn`t work. How do I fix this?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean exactly. Is there an extra "great keep playing\n" in the output you don't want?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include actual output (copy-pasted text; not a screen-shot) and what you wanted it to produce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue I see is that you get the value of restart on the 'cin' line, then display 'great keep playing' on the next line, without first checking to see what the value of 'restart' is.  You need an if() statement around the 'great keep playing' line, so it will only be displayed if you entered 'y'.

Answer (score 2):

You could write the loop like this:

```
while (cin >> restart && restart == 'y')
{
    cout << "great keep playing\n";
}
```